# Why is my svg crisp when imported, but blurry as a cursor?

Tags: html, css, svg

I was trying to use the following svg image as a cursor for my document:

```html
<svg height="128" width="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 144 135.92"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ef0000;}</style></defs><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M72,135.92,52.25,103c-.54-.91-.59-7.11.32-8.23l1-1.16,8.06,1.18V78.2H42.18l1.17,7.53-.81.93c-1.47,1.69-7.86.93-8.27.75L0,68,34,48.6c.6-.29,6.9-.9,8.34.48l1,1-1.18,7.61H61.63V41.1l-8.1,1.21-1-1.17c-.91-1.11-.86-7.32-.33-8.21L72,0,91.75,32.91c.5.85.68,7-.3,8.23l-1,1.17-8-1.19V57.7h19.36L100.61,50l1.08-1c1.41-1.27,7.62-.73,8-.54L144,68,110,87.3c-.65.3-6.95,1-8.42-.54l-.91-1,1.17-7.55H82.37V94.8l8.12-1.19,1,1.16c1,1.22.8,7.38.31,8.21Zm-14.82-35L72,125.58l14.82-24.7c0-.36,0-.85,0-1.35L77.05,101V73h31l-1.45,9.37H108L133.24,68l-25.3-14.4h-1.38L108,63H77.14V35l9.67,1.44c0-.51,0-1,0-1.36L72,10.34,57.18,35c0,.36,0,.85,0,1.36L67,34.92V63H36l1.45-9.4H36L10.76,68l25.3,14.37h1.38L36,72.88H66.91v28.06L57.2,99.52C57.19,100,57.18,100.52,57.18,100.89Z"/></g></g></svg>
<svg height="16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 144 135.92"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ef0000;}</style></defs><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M72,135.92,52.25,103c-.54-.91-.59-7.11.32-8.23l1-1.16,8.06,1.18V78.2H42.18l1.17,7.53-.81.93c-1.47,1.69-7.86.93-8.27.75L0,68,34,48.6c.6-.29,6.9-.9,8.34.48l1,1-1.18,7.61H61.63V41.1l-8.1,1.21-1-1.17c-.91-1.11-.86-7.32-.33-8.21L72,0,91.75,32.91c.5.85.68,7-.3,8.23l-1,1.17-8-1.19V57.7h19.36L100.61,50l1.08-1c1.41-1.27,7.62-.73,8-.54L144,68,110,87.3c-.65.3-6.95,1-8.42-.54l-.91-1,1.17-7.55H82.37V94.8l8.12-1.19,1,1.16c1,1.22.8,7.38.31,8.21Zm-14.82-35L72,125.58l14.82-24.7c0-.36,0-.85,0-1.35L77.05,101V73h31l-1.45,9.37H108L133.24,68l-25.3-14.4h-1.38L108,63H77.14V35l9.67,1.44c0-.51,0-1,0-1.36L72,10.34,57.18,35c0,.36,0,.85,0,1.36L67,34.92V63H36l1.45-9.4H36L10.76,68l25.3,14.37h1.38L36,72.88H66.91v28.06L57.2,99.52C57.19,100,57.18,100.52,57.18,100.89Z"/></g></g></svg>
```

```
html {
    cursor: url(cursor/move.svg), auto;
}
```

But it doesn't matter if I change its size to something big (128px) or small, and it doesn't matter if I'm on Chrome, Firefox, or Safari, it is still somewhat pixelated. It is crisp and clean when I import it into the HTML document, but blurry and pixelated when I use it as a cursor. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When SVG images are rendered, horizontal and vertical lines that follow integer coordinates will be spread across the two pixels on either side (above/below horizontal lines, and to the left/right of vertical lines). This makes them appear blurry.

To avoid this, create your design using integer coordinates, then offset the results by half a pixel in the X and Y directions. The results will be much sharper.

Also, it would make more sense to draw the cursor at the dimensions you want instead of at a much larger size that you have to scale down.

Here's a simple cursor drawn with and without a half-pixel offset. You should be able to see it much more clearly with the added offset.

```html
<!-- Lines following integer coordinates -->
<svg height="16" width="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M8,1L10.5,4L9,4L9,7L12,7L12,5.5L15,8
         L12,10.5L12,9L9,9L9,12L10.5,12L8,15
         L5.5,12L7,12L7,9L4,9L4,10.5L1,8L4,5.5
         L4,7L7,7L7,4L5.5,4L8,1Z" fill="none"
         stroke="#e00" stroke-width="0.8"
         stroke-miterlimit="2"/>
</svg>

<!-- Lines offset by half a pixel -->
<svg height="16" width="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M8.5,1.5L11,4.5L9.5,4.5L9.5,7.5
         L12.5,7.5L12.5,6L15.5,8.5L12.5,11
         L12.5,9.5L9.5,9.5L9.5,12.5L11,12.5
         L8.434,15.5L6,12.5L7.5,12.5L7.5,9.5
         L4.5,9.5L4.5,11L1.5,8.5L4.5,6L4.5,7.5
         L7.5,7.5L7.5,4.5L6,4.5L8.5,1.5Z"
         fill="none" stroke="#e00"
         stroke-width="0.8" stroke-miterlimit="2"/>
</svg>
```

### Example:

This is what the second of these images looks like when used as a cursor (i.e., the one offset by ½ a pixel):

```css
* {
    cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='16' width='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M8.5,1.5L11,4.5L9.5,4.5L9.5,7.5L12.5,7.5L12.5,6L15.5,8.5L12.5,11L12.5,9.5L9.5,9.5L9.5,12.5L11,12.5L8.434,15.5L6,12.5L7.5,12.5L7.5,9.5L4.5,9.5L4.5,11L1.5,8.5L4.5,6L4.5,7.5L7.5,7.5L7.5,4.5L6,4.5L8.5,1.5Z' fill='none' stroke='#e00' stroke-width='0.8' stroke-miterlimit='2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 8 8, move;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. For some reason, when I integrate the svg you have created as a cursor, it is still pixelated. Is there anything that I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I've no idea. It's working fine for me. I've edited the answer to show how it's supposed to look.

Answer (score 2):

I've just updated cursor to look like the following, I don't know if that helps:

```css
html {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: gold;
  
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='128px' height='128px' viewBox='0 0 512 512' style='enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;' xml:space='preserve'%3E %3Cpath d='M72,135.92,52.25,103c-.54-.91-.59-7.11.32-8.23l1-1.16,8.06,1.18V78.2H42.18l1.17,7.53-.81.93c-1.47,1.69-7.86.93-8.27.75L0,68,34,48.6c.6-.29,6.9-.9,8.34.48l1,1-1.18,7.61H61.63V41.1l-8.1,1.21-1-1.17c-.91-1.11-.86-7.32-.33-8.21L72,0,91.75,32.91c.5.85.68,7-.3,8.23l-1,1.17-8-1.19V57.7h19.36L100.61,50l1.08-1c1.41-1.27,7.62-.73,8-.54L144,68,110,87.3c-.65.3-6.95,1-8.42-.54l-.91-1,1.17-7.55H82.37V94.8l8.12-1.19,1,1.16c1,1.22.8,7.38.31,8.21Zm-14.82-35L72,125.58l14.82-24.7c0-.36,0-.85,0-1.35L77.05,101V73h31l-1.45,9.37H108L133.24,68l-25.3-14.4h-1.38L108,63H77.14V35l9.67,1.44c0-.51,0-1,0-1.36L72,10.34,57.18,35c0,.36,0,.85,0,1.36L67,34.92V63H36l1.45-9.4H36L10.76,68l25.3,14.37h1.38L36,72.88H66.91v28.06L57.2,99.52C57.19,100,57.18,100.52,57.18,100.89Z'/%3E %3C/svg%3E"), pointer;
}
```

Comment: there still seems to be pixelation around the cursor

Comment: It works for me, what is your browser? Please try another browser and see an example online in order to know where is exactly the issue. (browser, image or implementation. )

Comment: https://imgur.com/1AqFIdN I know it is hard to tell from the screenshot, but in Safari, Firefox, or Chrome my cursor in your snippet still appear blurry or slightly pixelated.

Comment: I changed your exact implementation to 64px so that it is more apparent >>> https://imgur.com/SzzjUj1